# The more efficient way to generate this string

Tags: php

I've got an associative array of key value pairs (the key and the value are exactly the same based on how the system generates them). I'd like to implode just the keys or just the values (which doesn't matter) - is there a way to do that?

Right now I've got a foreach loop, and this foreach loop is iterating over the array to grab the value, adding it to the string, and adding a comma after. That obviously adds one more comma than I need, as I don't want a trailing comma.

i.e.

first iteration:

```
item1,
```

second iteration:

```
item1, item2,
```

third iteration:

```
item1, item2, item3,
```

etc.

What's the most efficient way to implode all of the keys, or all of the values of an array (but not both)? Is the foreach method the best way? If so, what's the best way to get rid of the trailing comma - use a $count variable, or just trim the final comma (seems like the latter would be more efficient, but feels less elegant).

Comment: The irony is that the answer is in the question `I'd like to **implode** just the keys or just the values (which doesn't matter)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is PHP; the built in functions can tackle this without the need for loops at all.

```
// For the keys
$output = implode(',', array_keys($myArr)).', '; // if you need that trailing comma
$output = implode(',', array_keys($myArr)); // without the trailing comma.

// For the values (note that the keys are discarded by the implode function)
$output = implode(',', $myArr).', '; // if you need that trailing comma
$output = implode(',', $myArr); // without the trailing comma.
```

Comment: Oh nice, it automatically discards the keys? Excellent. Great answer.